Removing the text from \addpoints in xsim
I have the following output

I would like to get rid of the extraneous "[x] points" (as the marks/points are given on the far right)
MWE:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multicol, adjustbox, booktabs, array, siunitx, color, pdfpages, calc, amsmath, amssymb, enumitem,float, subcaption, tikz, titlesec, tikzpagenodes, bookmark,tabularray, graphicx, hyperref, multido,xsim,tcolorbox,pgfplots,biblatex, geometry}

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{question}{%
  {%
    \textbf{\GetExerciseName~\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}%
    \IfInsideSolutionF{%
      \GetExercisePropertyT{points}{ % notice the space
        (%
        \printgoal{\PropertyValue}
        \IfExerciseGoalSingularTF{points}
          {mark}
          {marks}%
        )%
      }\hfill \GetExercisePropertyT{subtitle}{ \textsc{\PropertyValue}}\\
    }}}

\xsimsetup{
  exercise/name={Question},
  solution/print=true,
  solution/name=Answer,
}

\DeclareExerciseType{question}{
  exercise-env = question,
  solution-env = answer,
  exercise-name = Question,
  solution-name = Answer,
  exercise-template = question,
  solution-template = default
}

% Formatting parts/subparts
\NewDocumentEnvironment{parts}{} % No arguments for the parts environment
{%
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)] % Define the label format as (a), (b), etc.
  \setcounter{enumi}{0} % Ensure the list starts from (a)
}%
{%
  \end{enumerate} % Properly close the enumerate
}

\def\part[#1]#2{%
  \item #2 \addpoints{#1} \hfill \textbf{#1} % Add and display points if provided
}

\xsimsetup{
  exercise/template = question ,
}

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{left=0.8in,right=0.8in,bottom=20mm,top=20mm, hcentering=true}

\begin{exercise}[subtitle={source}]
\begin{parts}
  \part[2] {question part 1}
  \part[4] {question part 2}
\end{parts}
\end{exercise}

\end{document}


Please remove all unnecessary packages from your minimal working example (MWE).

The \addpoint command is documented in the section 7.3, A Special Kind of Property: Exercise Goals of the xsim package:

\addpoints*{ ⟨value⟩ }
Adds ⟨value⟩ to the points of the current exercise type. (To be used within exercises.) Prints the value followed by an appropriate translation of the words “point” or “points”, respectively. The starred version prints nothing. Defined in terms of \AddtoExerciseGoal and \AddtoExerciseGoalPrint.

So simply use \addpoint*
\def\part[#1]#2{%
  \item #2 \addpoints*{#1} \hfill \textbf{#1} % Add and display points if provided
}

Example:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, enumitem, xsim}

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{question}{%
  {%
    \textbf{\GetExerciseName~\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}%
    \IfInsideSolutionF{%
      \GetExercisePropertyT{points}{ % notice the space
        (%
        \printgoal{\PropertyValue}
        \IfExerciseGoalSingularTF{points}
          {mark}
          {marks}%
        )%
      }\hfill \GetExercisePropertyT{subtitle}{ \textsc{\PropertyValue}}\\
    }}}

\xsimsetup{
  exercise/name={Question},
  solution/print=true,
  solution/name=Answer,
}

\DeclareExerciseType{question}{
  exercise-env = question,
  solution-env = answer,
  exercise-name = Question,
  solution-name = Answer,
  exercise-template = question,
  solution-template = default
}

% Formatting parts/subparts
\NewDocumentEnvironment{parts}{} % No arguments for the parts environment
{%
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)] % Define the label format as (a), (b), etc.
  \setcounter{enumi}{0} % Ensure the list starts from (a)
}%
{%
  \end{enumerate} % Properly close the enumerate
}

\def\part[#1]#2{%
  \item #2 \addpoints*{#1} \hfill \textbf{#1} % Add and display points if provided
}

\xsimsetup{
  exercise/template = question ,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}[subtitle={source}]
\begin{parts}
  \part[2] {question part 1}
  \part[4] {question part 2}
\end{parts}
\end{exercise}

\end{document}


